# Could not parse mapping document error in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is my first post in stackoverflow:
I am new to hibernate, infact below is my first code in hibernate:
i am repetedly getting "could not parse mapping document" error, when i run my main class.
below is the code for your refernce, please help me out of this.

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">one</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">two</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <mapping resource="EmployeeMapping.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE"/>
  <id name="emp_id" type="int" column="emp_id"/>

  <property name="emp_name">
      <column name="emp_name"/>
  </property>

  <property name="emp_branch">
      <column name="emp_branch"/>
  </property>
  <property name="emp_Salary">
      <column name="emp_salary"/>
  </property>
  <property name="emp_fav_dgt">
      <column name="emp_fav_dgt"/>
  </property>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Pojo class:

```
public class Employee {

    private int emp_id;
    private String emp_name;
    private String emp_branch;
    private int emp_Salary;
    private int emp_fav_dgt;

    public int getEmp_Salary() {
        return emp_Salary;
    }

    public void setEmp_Salary(int emp_Salary) {
        this.emp_Salary = emp_Salary;
    }

    public String getEmp_branch() {
        return emp_branch;
    }

    public void setEmp_branch(String emp_branch) {
        this.emp_branch = emp_branch;
    }

    public int getEmp_fav_dgt() {
        return emp_fav_dgt;
    }

    public void setEmp_fav_dgt(int emp_fav_dgt) {
        this.emp_fav_dgt = emp_fav_dgt;
    }

    public int getEmp_id() {
        return emp_id;
    }

    public void setEmp_id(int emp_id) {
        this.emp_id = emp_id;
    }

    public String getEmp_name() {
        return emp_name;
    }

    public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
        this.emp_name = emp_name;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("asdf");
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
         Transaction ts = null;
         Session session = null;
         Configuration conf = null;
        try{
            conf =  new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure();
            sessionFactory =  conf.buildSessionFactory();
            session =sessionFactory.openSession();
            Employee customer = new Employee();
            customer.setEmp_id(1);
            customer.setEmp_name("one");
            customer.setEmp_branch("old");
            customer.setEmp_Salary(1000);
            customer.setEmp_fav_dgt(2);
            session.save(customer);
            ts.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
        finally{
           session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property tags corresponding with the fields should be nested within the class tag.

```
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
  <id name="emp_id" type="int" column="emp_id"/>

  <property name="emp_name">
      <column name="emp_name"/>
  </property>

  <property name="emp_branch">
      <column name="emp_branch"/>
  </property>
  <property name="emp_Salary">
      <column name="emp_salary"/>
  </property>
  <property name="emp_fav_dgt">
      <column name="emp_fav_dgt"/>
  </property>
</class>
```